# Хранение данных с дополнительного поля в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток и так вопрос:
У меня сейчас есть таблица данных с н-ым количеством столбцов и т.д. И есть к примеру 2 столбца, 1 для выбора категории допустим, другой для выбора исполнителя.
В БД запись попадает в виде ID. cat_id и emp_id.
Если не под одну категорию не попадает запись, то есть нет такой категории или же множество категории, как мне хранить данные? 
Создать pivot таблицу? Или же после заполнения кастомного инпут филда создавалась новая запись в таблице категории?
Как будет лучше и правильнее?

Comment: видимо нет категории - нет записи. много категорий - много записей. вообще вопрос не особо понятен

Comment: линн бейли sql почитай